# Did Satoshi Nakamoto (in his blogs or the whitepaper) forecast that mining pools would exist?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, majority-attack, satoshi-nakamoto

Mining pools are common today where users pool their resources together and share profits accordingly. Such pools today can account for significant proportions of a network's hash power and they're are risks shold a coalition of malicious parties form a pool with 51% of the mining power.

My question is, did Satoshi ever forsee this coming or consider it as a possibility that may arise? Did Satoshi ever provide any thought about the positive/negative implications of the existence of mining pools?

Answer (score 1):

Nakamoto did discuss the idea when others brought up the notion of cooperative mining, but I don't know if he wrote about it before anyone else came up with the idea.

You can search an archive of Nakamoto's communications

https://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/posts/bitcointalk/threads/250/?view=satoshi

> ribuck's description is spot on.
>
> Pool operators can modify their getwork to take one additional parameter, the address to send your share to.
>
> The easy way for the pool operator would be to wait until the next block is found and divy it up proportionally as:
>
> user's near-hits/total near-hits from everyone